# After Plugin deinstallation, Login impossible and line50 error

Tags: fatal-error

I have a big problem with my website. I wanted to edit this and have updated and uninstalled plugins that I thought I no longer need (or never needed) but apparently this was not the case.
As soon as I want to open my website, this appears:

Fatal error: Can't use function return value in write context in /home2/mafiabea/public_html/wp-content/plugins/coming-soon/app/load_controller.php on line 50

I can no longer log into my Wordpress account either, nothing is possible anymore.
The site is very important to showcase our bugalows and I am not sure how to solve this problem.

I thank you for every help and every tip!

Michelle :)

Answer (score 3):

If you have access to your cpanel, or equivalent in your hosting, you can disable the plugin manually.

Go to file manager, find your root folder, ususaly under public, public_html or www, something like that.

Now go to wp-content -> plugins -> plugin folder, im guessing the plugin folder will be named coming-soon or something similar.

Rename the plugin folder to something else, coming-soon1 or whatever.

This will disable it and, most likely if not other error occur, you will be able to see your site and login without problems.